# Ubuntu unable to install .Net Core

Tags: apt

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on virtual machine and trying to install .Net core.

I have followed following link for [Installing .Net Core on Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu)

I tried to install package but it's failing.

Here i am putting output please check it once.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702 : Depends: dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.0-rc2-3002702 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.0-rc2-3002702
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.0-rc2-3002702 : Depends: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 i found that .Net core is still not supported in 16.04 and maximum support is provide is up to 15.10.

[Ubuntu - Installing .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322843/ubuntu-installing-net-core)

Why there is no note on Installing .Net core in Ubuntu page about what version of Ubuntu should be used?

Is it correct that .Net Core is still not supported in Ubuntu 16.04? Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried installing https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/libicu52 as suggested in the comments to the answer you've linked to? There's another comment that even says it works in 16.04.

Comment: @Tobias. Yes i have already install libicu55

Comment: The installer claims _“you have held broken packages”_. You should uninstall / reinstall them before moving on.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322843/ubuntu-installing-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to install the dependant package dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app will get you next error, saying that this package depends on libicu52 but it is not installable

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/pl/trusty/amd64/libicu52/download
```

and download .deb package. Now, go to the download location and install the package by running:

```
sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
```

Now, you will be able to run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.0-rc2-3002702
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702

dotnet --version
```

Good luck

source: http://zablo.net/blog/post/run-and-debug-asp-net-core-rc2-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

You could run

> sudo apt-get install -f

to solve some errors automatically. 
From `man apt`:

```
-f, --fix-broken Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

It'll install missing packages or dependencies.